# change text color on disabled button (custom ButtonRenderer)

Tags: c#, android, button, xamarin, colors

I use `Xamarin.Forms`, I create custom Renderer `FlatButtonRenderer` for Android. I want to add to it only one parametr - white text color on disabled button. What easy way to do it? On enabled button I simple can change `Button.TextColor` in `PCL` project. If way to change text color on disabled with c# code?

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Button), typeof(ugrid.Droid.FlatButtonRenderer))]

namespace myProject.Droid
{
    public class FlatButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnDraw(Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.OnDraw(canvas);
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use custom renderers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49193488/1039935

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like you would be better using a style with a trigger rather than a custom renderer. An example for a button changing background to red on disabled would look something like this:

```
    <Button Command="{Binding Command}" Text="Blah Button">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger TargetType="Button"  Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

This could also be done in the code behind if required. If the style is used elsewhere you would want to add it to the resources and reference it.

If you want to change the style just for the one platform, use the "OnPlatform"

Comment: But I want Save all paramerts style. This way saved all?

Comment: please re-phrase your comment, it does not make sense

Comment: i want to save standard animation of button. it's will be ?

Comment: the code above would not change any existing animation code

Comment: but I must create custom control button renderer because standart conrol button xamarin.forms has bug with border radius and width. If any way to change text disabled button in this renderer?

Comment: try it, depending on what you've done in your custom renderer it could still work. it really depends on how much you've modified with the custom renderer.

Comment: unfortunatelly, it doesn't work textcolor for disabled button don't change